# Can I put patio style wooden planks on this roofing material on my patio?

Tags: hardwood-floor, patio, roofing

My second floor patio is covered with this material. It looks like asphalt roofing material, but I am not sure. Can someone please help me identify it? Also, can I put wooden patio style planks over it? There would be about 3/4 inch gab between the planks and the roofing material.

I should add - this is in southern California and the area is not roofed. It occasionally rains there, but rarely.

[image]

[image]

Edit: I thought I would show you the finished work. I am pretty happy how it turned out. Thank you for your advice!

[image]

Comment: You should consider 'interlocking deck tiles'.  They come in wood or stone and don't lay flat on the surface so moisture isn't trapped.

Comment: I don't like the look of it as much as that of wood planks, though.

Comment: the technical term for that arrangmet of planks is "duckboard".  and that seems like a good plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to me like a liquid applied elastomeric urethane deck coating with broadcast sand which has been overlaid by another coating of the liquid membrane. This is quite typically used for waterproofing decks above living spaces or under second floor tile decks.

It is fine to put your boards on top if you only fasten them to the horizontal runner boards and make no penetrations through the desk surface coating.